# UWP XAML Templated Control - "Edit a Copy" Disabled

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

In my Solution I have a UWP App and a UWP class library (both target Windows 10 Build 10240).

I've added a Templated Control to the class library. This control inherits from Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control as per:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = GRID_CONTAINER_PART_NAME, Type = typeof(Grid))]
[TemplatePart(Name = CAPTURE_ELEMENTPREVIEW_PART_NAME, Type = typeof(CaptureElement))]
[TemplatePart(Name = CANVAS_PREVIEW_PART_NAME, Type = typeof(Canvas))]
[TemplatePart(Name = TEXTBLOCK_STATUS_PART_NAME, Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
public sealed class FaceDetectorPreview : Control
```

(I've chosen to derive from Templated Control so that the control is deployable to different Apps and to give a developer the ability to change the look and feel of the components)

In the App, I can add the Control to a XAML page, run the App and everything works fine.

However, in the Designer, when I choose "Edit Template" the "Edit a Copy" menu item is disabled.

**Q. What do I need to change to make the Edit a Copy menu item available?**

The code in Generic.xaml is show below:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="using:FaceDetection.Controls">

<Style TargetType="local:FaceDetectorPreview">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:FaceDetectorPreview">

                <Grid x:Name="PART_GridContainer">
                    <CaptureElement x:Name="PART_CaptureElementPreview" />
                    <Canvas x:Name="PART_CanvasPreview" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="PART_TextBlockStatus" />
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick answer to my own question. I will provide a fuller explanation later.

**A**. The "Edit a Copy" menu item is not available if the Build Configuration for the UWP App is set to "x64". If I change it to "x86" it is available.